# How best to clear innerHTML of elements inside a div without removing the elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, element

I'm trying to clear the data that's in each child element of a parent element without removing (or hiding) the actual child elements.

To reproduce the problem:

- Enter data for `Test1` and `Test2`
- Click the checkbox 'Use actual data' and enter data for `Test 3` and `Test 4`.
- Press the button to 'Clear Element Data for Tests 1 & 2'.

This is intended to remove the `innerHTML` data, not the elements itself.

I want the elements to remain visible and usable, just empty of any data. I only want the data to be cleared.

How can I do this?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#actual").click(function() {
    if ($("#actual").is(":checked")) {
      $("#utility-info").hide();
      $("#actual-utils").show();
    } else {
      $("#utility-info").show();
      $("#actual-utils").hide();
    }
  });

  $("#clear-values").click(function() {
    $("#utility-info").html('');
  });
});
```

```css
#actual-utils {
  display: none;
}

span {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="actual" name="actual-util-info"> Use actual data
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div id="energy-info">
  <div id="utility-info">
    <div>Test 1 <input id="test1" type="number" name="test1"></div>
    <div>Test 2 <input id="test2" type="number" name="test2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="actual-utils">
    <div>Test 3 <input id="actual1" type="number" name="actual1"></div>
    <div>Test 4 <input id="actual2" type="number" name="actual2"></div>
  </div>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <button id="clear-values">Clear Element Data for Tests 1 & 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're clearing the *entire* content of `#utility-info`, which contains the `input` elements as well as their values.

To fix the issue, change your selector to directly target the `input` elements and then use `val('')` to clear the values.

Also note that you can improve the logic and make it more succinct by caching the jQuery objects you create when making the calls to the DOM, and by using the `toggle()` method to hide/show the `div` elements based on the boolean `checked` property of the checkbox.

Here's a working example:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  const $utilityInfo = $('#utility-info');
  const $actualUtils = $('#actual-utils');

  $('#actual').on('click', e => {
    const useActual = e.target.checked;
    $utilityInfo.toggle(!useActual);
    $actualUtils.toggle(useActual);
  });

  $('#clear-values').click(function() {
    $utilityInfo.find('input').val('');
  });
});
```

```css
#actual-utils {
  display: none;
}

span {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="actual" name="actual-util-info"> Use actual data
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div id="energy-info">
  <div id="utility-info">
    <div>Test 1 <input id="test1" type="number" name="test1"></div>
    <div>Test 2 <input id="test2" type="number" name="test2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="actual-utils">
    <div>Test 3 <input id="actual1" type="number" name="actual1"></div>
    <div>Test 4 <input id="actual2" type="number" name="actual2"></div>
  </div>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <button id="clear-values">Clear Element Data for Tests 1 & 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This will work.  The logic too.

Answer (score 0):

The "*best™*" might be to actually use declarative HTML that can do all this for you without JS. A `<form>`, and all its inner `<input>` elements, can be reset, to their original values, by a `<button type="reset">` (or an equivalent `<input type="reset">`).

Besides being totally clear to AT, and machines what your markup is about, and to work where JS is disabled, it allows you to set an initial value and to reset it back.

```css
/* Toggle the checkbox to show one form at a time */
#actual:checked ~ * #utility-info,
#actual:not(:checked) ~ * #actual-utils {
  display: none;
}
span {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="actual" name="actual-util-info"> Use actual data
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div id="energy-info">
  <!-- Wrap in <form> elements -->
  <form id="utility-info">
    <div>Test 1 <input id="test1" type="number" name="test1"></div>
    <div>Test 2 <input id="test2" type="number" name="test2"></div>
  </form>
  <!-- Wrap in <form> elements -->
  <form id="actual-utils">
    <div>Test 3 <input id="actual1" type="number" name="actual1"></div>
    <div>Test 4 <input id="actual2" type="number" name="actual2"></div>
  </form>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <!--
    Since our reset button is outside the <form>
    We use the form="" attribute to point to the correct one.
  -->
  <button id="clear-values" type="reset" form="utility-info">Clear Element Data for Tests 1 &amp; 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a man-made form using Google Sheets, a spreadsheet that's being converted to a web app.   It does about 20 calculations based on the inputs of the form.

I could create the form, click a **Results** button, and then have JS display the results.

Comment: @MarkStout doesn't change much. The most semantic way of clearing a set of inputs is to `reset()` their owner `<form>`.

Comment: That's just it.  This isn't inside a `<form>`.  There's `<div>` holding `<input>` and `<select>`, laid out like a `<form>`, and then the calculations are done and shown using `.text()`.  I could place everything inside a `<form>`.  It's going into a database eventually.

Comment: A div is never semantic. A form is what your divs are used for. Better use the correct element from the get go, no?